# Android Eclipse : How to resolve third party library dependencies corresponding to gradle build

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am porting an android application project built with non-eclipse tool, with gradle in use, perhaps the tool was Android Studio. I have the .zip file of the project. So, far I have put all `layout`,`values` and `drawables` in place. I am stuck at the last step of dependencies.

The project depends on [Github : BlueJamesBond](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) library and many others. This is the `build.gradle` dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.6'
}
```

Now, the `BlueJamesBond` itself is using gradle and I have no idea how gradle works. I was expecting some jar of the library which I could have added in Build Path. Can anyone please suggest how to resolve the dependency in my project?

Comment: go to each dependency and dowload .jar or .aar files and add them to libs folder in your project if using eclipse

Comment: @RaviTeja : I have already tried looking for `.jar`s. Please read the question carefully. There is only source code available for the library and that itself is using gradle.... Or if you can advise how to compile https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android into jar would be helpful.

Comment: all you need to do is run the gradle build task, it will download all the dependencies for you. Goto to the root directory of your project (one where you have the gradlew file) and run `./gradlew build`

Comment: @Bhargav : Can I do in eclipse? I am a newbie in android development and know basic android development. I also have used third party libraries using Build Path --> Add jar. But gradle/maven etc. are all new to me. I don't want to go into deep in them. Can you suggest a way or link to a tutorial which takes one of the third party library as an example and teaches how to import in android application.... usage of github sources would be preferred....

Comment: If you are a newbie, why not use android studio itself? it has a graphical interface for running gradle tasks, you wouldn't need to do all these changes for it. and the above command I said is to be run in your terminal/cmd prompt

Comment: clone the project and try importing the library module from the repo into your eclipse project that should help.