# Gradle Build : error package does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I was developing an android app (using Eclipse, not Studio) following some example, which makes use of [Github/CircleImageView](https://github.com/AlexZhukovich/CircleImageView). Hence, I wanted to compile that first into a jar library.

So on my Linux machine I installed gradle and since its my first time with gradle, I followed the [tutorial on gradle](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/). So, in the root directory of the project `~/Downloads/CircleImageView-master/`, I :

1. Run `gradle wrapper`. Got Build Success
2. Run `./gradlew build`, gives the following error

   CircleImageView.java:21: error: package com.nineoldandroids.animation does not exist

   import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator;

Though, I can see that there is one jar file in the project `~/Downloads/CircleImageView-master/circleimageview/libs/nineoldandroid-library-2.4.0.jar`. Can anyone please help in resolving the issue. I am trying since past 10 hours and reached so far here after resolving all the issues, and stuck just at the last point.

I opened the jar in a package manager and the required classes are there, including `ObjectAnimator`.

Comment: Why did you clone the project? You can include the library with `compile 'com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.2.0'`

Comment: @cricket_007 : I am using Eclipse for development (not Studio, else it would have been straightforward, perhaps). I also asked the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940391/android-eclipse-how-to-resolve-third-party-library-dependencies-corresponding and after searching a lot for hours, I thought of compiling using gradle, as the last option. So far, I got success with gradle compilation also, but it seems gradle is not able to see the package `com.nineoldandroids.animation` which is present there. Where gradle searches for libs?

Comment: I think that library is deprecated, last time I checked. If you see the jar file, then that's how Gradle searches. Anyways, Eclipse Neon has Gradle support, so you could still use that line, if you feel like converting your project

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but most libraries, you'll probably want an AAR file, not just a JAR file. The AAR includes additional android specific resources

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thanks. Basically why all this mess is because I am trying to run an Android Studio Project into Eclipse. But it seems its not possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745793/how-do-you-open-an-android-studio-project-in-eclipse. The answer there is 3 years old, though.

Comment: You could try using "Andmore", or you could just get Android Studio... Eclipse does support Gradle now (you might have up update Eclipse)